# Recurrence relation for $J_n = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^n e^{-x^2} dx$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, recurrence-relations

For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we note $J_n = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} x^n e^{-x^2} dx$ and we remind that $J_0 = \sqrt{\pi}$.

We have to calculate $J_1$ and write a recurrence relation which allow to calculate $J_n$ for all $n \geq 0$.

I notice that $J_n = 0$ when $n$ is odd. But how to find the recurrence relation when $n$ is even ?

Comment: Integrating by parts removes two factors of $x$ (one from the differentiation, another from the integration), thereby relating $J_n$ to $J_{n-2}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

Integrate by parts, $$I_n=\int x^{n-1}xe^{-x^2}dx=x^{n-1}\int xe^{-x^2}dx-\int\left(\dfrac{d(x^{n-1})}{dx}\cdot \int xe^{-x^2}dx\right)dx$$

Now set $-x^2=y,\displaystyle\int2xe^{-x^2}dx=-\int e^y\ dy=-e^{-x^2}+K$

Answer (score 2):

I'll offer an alternative to integration by parts: differentiation under the integral sign. Define $I_n:=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}x^{2n}e^{-ax^2}dx=J_{2n}a^{-n-1/2}$ so $I_n=-\partial_aI_{n-1}=(n-\frac{1}{2})\frac{I_n}{a}$. Setting $a=1$, $J_{2n}=(n-\frac{1}{2})J_{2n-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

By integration by parts, one has
\begin{eqnarray}
J_{2n}&=&-\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2n-1}d(e^{-x^2})\\
&=&-\frac{1}{2}x^{2n-1}e^{-x^2}\bigg|_{-\infty}^{\infty}+\frac{2n-1}{2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}x^{2n-2}e^{-x^2}dx\\
&=&\frac{2n-1}{2}J_{2(n-1)}.
\end{eqnarray}